# Set a value as integer when creating a new entity in Azure Table with Logic App

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

When creating a new entity in Azure Table with Logic App, they all end up strings variables. How can I set my value counter to be an integer ?

{
  "PartitionKey":"Phone",
  "Counter": "1",
  "RowKey": "1",
  "Name:"Bob"
}

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the JSON payload without double quotations around the counter value.

{ "PartitionKey":"Phone", "Counter": 1, "RowKey": "1", "Name:"Bob" }